# Como mostrar un div al cargar la pagina

Tags: javascript, html

actualmente tengo un div oculto

```
 <div id="llave" style="display: none">
   //aca esta el contenido
 </div>
```

pero lo que busco es que cuando termine de cargar la pagina se muestre.

estuve intentando asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).load(function() {
 document.getElementById('llave').style.display='block';
 });
</script>
```

pero no resulta... habra alguna manera de que se pueda dar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que estas usando jQuery.  En ese caso puedes usar `$(document).ready()` y `.show()`.  Quedaria asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#llave').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="llave" style="display: none">
   //aca esta el contenido
</div>
```

Comment: claro, estaba usando el jquery... gracias por el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#llave").show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: gracias por responder bro, ese era el codigo que buscaba